# Java JPanel import image using eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, image, swing, jpanel

I am using eclipse and wondering where to put an image so that I can import it into java. I am trying to import an image called viewport.png into JPanel from a folder called pictures that I have placed in my src folder within my workspace. This is what I have tried:

```
private Image viewport = new ImageIcon("src/images/viewport.png").getImage();
```

then of course later,

```
g.drawImage(viewport, 2, 2, null);
```

I really just want to be able to import a picture from the same folder, as this project is being moved to another computer where it will have a different path, but still be in the same folder. I was wondering if there is a shortcut to finding it that way (just be looking in the same folder as the classes are in).

Comment: The image is stored in a folder called pictures in the src folder and you are referencing src/images

Comment: oh whoops i didn't catch that typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access the image via the classpath. You can do it by using `getClass().getResource()` which returns an `URL` you can pass the `ImageIcon(URL)` or `ImageIO.read(URL)` (which returns an `Image`. The latter is preferred, as an exception will be thrown is something is wrong with the path

```
BufferedImage viewPort;
...
try {
    viewPort = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/pictures/viewport.png"));
} catch (IOException ex) { 
    // print some message 
}
```

Your `pictures` should be in the `src`

```
ProjectRoot
         src
            pictures
                  viewport.png
```

Comment: The same way you currently are. `g.drawImage(viewport,2,2,this)`. The `try/catch` you probably want to put in the constructor of your panel class.